# Rust: Weird error message when using enum for new struct

Tags: rust

Sorry for the imprecise title, but I do not know how to describe this.

I have the following code (some parts left out):

```rust
enum ContainerType {
        ///a full 20 foot container for the specific full container pickup request
        Full20(usize),
        ///any empty 20 foot container, which one makes no difference
        Empty20,
        ///a full 40 foot container for the specific full container pickup request
        Full40(usize),
        ///an empty 40 foot container, which one makes no difference
        Empty40,
        ///no container at all
        NoContainer,
    }

pub struct SearchState {
        ///current node in the distance/time matrix
        current_node: usize,
        path_options: Vec<PathOption>,
        container_1: ContainerType,
        container_2: ContainerType,
        requests_visisted: u64,
        previous_state: PreviousState,
    }

impl SearchState{
  fn create_next_one_changing_containers(
            config: &Config,
            previous_state: SearchState,
            path_options: Vec<PathOption>,
        ) -> SearchState {
            //this function should only be called when at least one path exists
            let current_node = path_options[0].get_current_node();
            let boxed_state = PreviousState::Previous(Box::new(previous_state));
            //do containers need to be changed/is the new node a request?
            let mut new_state;
            let new_state = SearchState {
                    current_node,
                    path_options,
                    container_1: previous_state.container_1,
                    container_2: previous_state.container_2,
                    requests_visisted: 0,
                    previous_state: boxed_state,
            };
            return new_state;
  }
}
```

This gives me an error message when trying to create `new_state`. In particular, the second container value gets marked with the message:

```
use of moved value: `previous_state.container_2`

value used here after moverustc(E0382)
solver.rs(134, 13): move occurs because `previous_state` has type `solver::solver_data::SearchState`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
solver.rs(139, 64): value moved here
solver.rs(149, 34): value used here after move
```

I do not get this. The error message refers to the type of `previous_state` but `container_2` is an enum. Also, it should be trivial to copy it. I also tried adding `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` over the enum definition, but this did not change anything.
I previously got another error message for `requests_visited` with a similar content, when I tried using the value from `previous_state`, but this one went away once I just replaced it with a constant to debug the other problems first.
I have no idea why this happens and hope someone can at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: You moved the `previous_state` object under ownerwhip of `boxed_state`

Comment: Since your enum is fairly fast to copy, you can `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` the enum and move the `previous_state` not in a separate variable, but inline `let new_state = SearchState { ... previous_state: PreviousState::Previous(Box::new(previous_state)), }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call **PreviousState::Previous(Box::new(previous_state))** you move the variable **previous_state** becase the signature of new is **pub fn new(x: T)** which captures by values, thus moving your variable.

If you want to avoid the error, you can make your state struct to derive the **Clone** trait (careful because all members of the struct will need to derive that trait) and create the boxed_state as this:

```
let boxed_state = PreviousState::Previous(Box::new(previous_state.clone()));
```

I think you will have the same move problem when you create the new_state because **previous_state.container_1** has type **ContainerType** which does not implement **Copy** trait. To fix the issue:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum ContainerType {
        ///a full 20 foot container for the specific full container pickup request
        Full20(usize),
        ///any empty 20 foot container, which one makes no difference
        Empty20,
        ///a full 40 foot container for the specific full container pickup request
        Full40(usize),
        ///an empty 40 foot container, which one makes no difference
        Empty40,
        ///no container at all
        NoContainer,
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. As I mentioned I already tried adding this to the enum definition and it did not work, but I will need to change something else anyway.

Comment: Just to be sure: When I pass ownership/borrow a value as happens with `Box::new()`, the entire value is copied, it is not just a temporary change in some ownership variable in the background?

Comment: Two things @LarsWigger, it's not copied, it's *moved* - which is like a copy, but still, you must think of the separately or you run into this kind of thing.  And there's no "ownership variable" in the background, that's tracked at compile-time.  You need some time with [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#ways-variables-and-data-interact-move) and playing around with this concept.

Comment: As KevinAnderson mentioned, @LarsWigger, have a look at the ownership. As a rule of thumb, any function that accepts a paramater using its type **T** (its value), not the burrow (refference) **&T**, will cause the move semantic of Rust. The move semantic will be shown to you by the burrow checker at compile time if you attempt to use a variable whose resource (value) has been moved. If the type **T** implements copy trait, the copy semantic will be used, and you will be able to use that variable after the function that required that variable.